# how to add captions to Tumblr theme light box with this theme?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying to add some captions to the Klien tumblr theme. Ideally, when you click on the post image and the light box opens, I'd also like it to display the post caption/description.

Anyone able to help me out?

I know enough html to have a little tinker around but this is beyond me.
The site I'm playing around with is here:http://misftscaravan1.tumblr.com/

this is just a draft until I can get everything right.

I've been reading up for hours and am still scratching my head over this one.

Comment: You have your work cut out. The theme currently takes the post content and when you click on an image to open the lightbox, it opens the content in a separate container. This container does not have access to the individual post data (caption and description). So you would have to either reverse engineer the lightbox so that it opens inside the post content (so you can then also access the caption etc) or you could use a hack and clone those contents to the lightbox (along with the image).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look. 
Sounds beyond my skill level to be honest. Do you think it would be possible to hack it and install a different light box all together?

Comment: I was thinking about this. The best option is to try and find a template which loads posts via ajax. Try searching for Tumblr template post ajax (I couldn't find anything yesterday but I know they exist)

Comment: Thank you- I'll take a look into that. This is great because I'm learning along the way. This is what I've got to so far- forgive my terrible hacking- I've changed a few things haha www.aimee-young.com